# python rabbitmqadmin list queues command doesn't obtain messages content although messages exist

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmqadmin

I am learning rabbitMq and and now I want to know how to wath queue content.

First of all I want to day that I googled this question and know about command

```
python rabbitmqadmin list queues
```

I have written 2 separated applications.

**sender:**

```
@Autowired
private AmqpTemplate template;
 ...

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        template.convertAndSend("queue1", "message_" + i);
  }
```

**receiver:**

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue1")
public void listenQueue1(String message, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) {
    logger.info("Got message:[" + message + "]");
}
```

If I run these applications together - I see messages on receiver side.

To see messages in the queue I decided to stop `receiver` and run `sender`

1. I run sender
2. execute `python rabbitmqadmin list queues`

and see following result:

```
+-----------------+----------+
|      name       | messages |
+-----------------+----------+
| query-example-6 |          |
| queue1          |          |
| queue2          |          |
| queue3          |          |
| queue4          |          |
| queue5          |          |
| queue6          |          |
| queue7          |          |
| queue8          |          |
| queue9          |          |
+-----------------+----------+
```

3.Then I run receiver and see logs that receiver accepted messages

Can you clarify reason why I can't see messages in console?

How to see  queue messages content.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with rabbitmq.

maybe the message is "unacknowledged"?

e.g.  I found my queue has a message:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin list queues name node messages

+----------------------------+----------------+----------+
|            name            |      node      | messages |
+----------------------------+----------------+----------+
| my_queue_name              | rabbit@xx-2    | 1        |
```

but when I run "get" command to show its content, rabbitmq tells me "there's no item"

so, I query it with this command:

```
$ rabbitmqadmin list queues name node messages messages_ready messages_unacknowledged

+----------------------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+
|            name            |      node      | messages | messages_ready | messages_unacknowledged |
+----------------------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+
| my_queue_name              | rabbit@xxxxx-2 | 1        | 0              | 1                       |
+----------------------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

I don't know why. just restart the rabbitmq server and everything seems goes fine.